# Hive 2.1.0 Issue org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to move source

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, tez

I am using hadoop 2.7.2 , hive 2.1.0 have enabled tez and but reverted back to use mr as execution engine and facing below error while trying to run a Insert Select query on orc and parquet tables,

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to move source hdfs://.../user/hive/warehouse/access_logs.db/crawlstats_dpp/day=2016-10-18/.hive-staging_hive_2016-10-20_14-46-33_718_5449118624054166228-1/-ext-10000 to destination hdfs://..../user/hive/warehouse/access_logs.db/crawlstats_dpp/day=2016-10-18
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.moveFile(Hive.java:2959)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.replaceFiles(Hive.java:3198)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadPartition(Hive.java:1532)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadPartition(Hive.java:1461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask.execute(MoveTask.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1858)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1562)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1313)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1084)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1072)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: rename for src path: hdfs:.....:9000/user/hive/warehouse/access_logs.db/crawlstats_dpp/day=2016-10-18/.hive-staging_hive_2016-10-20_14-46-33_718_5449118624054166228-1/-ext-10000/000000_0 to dest:hdfs://.....:9000/user/hive/warehouse/access_logs.db/crawlstats_dpp/day=2016-10-18 returned false
```

Any clue about the issue, would be highly appriciated.

Regards.